# Magento will not make database backup anymore!

Tags: database, backup

I have a problem with the backup feature in Magento 1.8.1.0

I can't create backups anymore, using "System - tools - backup". It has been working fine before, but the last month, I will not work anymore.

When I start a backup, I can see it's working, but when it is finish, there is no backup file in the Var folder.

Someone who can guide me here ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe the var folder does not have the proper rights?

When the database grows bigger, the Magento backup function simply fails to do its job because it's too big to handle. Then you have to backup mysql directly.

Comment: The var folder has been working just fine for a long time, but I have not checked the settings of this folder lately. But I'll do that. I can only get the database backup to Work - it uses 32mb. The system and database+media does not Work. The last time these twoo backups worked, was august 19. They took up 88mb and 93mb. I don't know if that is too much ?

Answer (score 1):

As your database grows with more orders, customers and products it takes a longer to complete the backup. Potentially the time it takes to create the backup is now longer than what your server allows (for example php max_execution_time). If you do not have control over your server I would suggest getting in touch with your webhost/sysadmin to confirm why this times out (or errors, there might be an error message in your server's error log).

Comment: php max_execution_time - is that a file in my Magento installation, I can access and change my self ? Maybe change the timer ?

Comment: You might be able to override this with a php.ini file but again your host would be best placed in answering this. You might find that you need a better host soon.

Comment: I have a really god webhost I think. I just talked to them. There is no timeout function activated they told me. I just found the serverlog and will see if I can understand it. I have access to phpmyadmin and thought that I might be able to create a backup there instead. But is there a different in the backup using phpmyadmin and the one in Magento ?

Comment: I was just told from my webhost, that they create a backup of my hole database each day. I guess that this means, that I do not have to use the backup function in Magento anymore...or what ?

Comment: It's good that they do it, but if I was you I would only trust a backup that you have verified. For phpmyadmin backups see https://www.yireo.com/tutorials/magento/magento-administration/653-magento-backup-through-phpmyadmin

Answer (score 1):

Did you try to run the script??

```
php {magento-dir}/bin/magento setup:backup --db
php {magento-dir}/bin/magento setup:backup --code
php {magento-dir}/bin/magento setup:backup --media
```